# Voice Commands Using Microphone

Tags: xna, input, voice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Voice input in games beyond voip chat](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/voice-input-in-games-beyond-voip-chat)

I recently made a game  where you say something into the microphone, and the computer repeats it, but I was wondering how to make voice commands, where if you say a certain thing it does something. For example:

- I say "Blue" and the background color changes to blue.
- I say "Red" and the background color changes to red.

Comment: You're asking about voice recognition - the answer will be well and away from your current code, so you don't really need to supply it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Voice input in games beyond voip chat](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/); also related is [How can I get voice recognition features into the Unity Game Engine?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/) (which gives a non-UDK exclusive answer). But ultimately relevant: [Coding Horror: Whatever Happened to Voice Recognition?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/06/whatever-happened-to-voice-recognition.html) (it failed)